# DefaultValues of react-hook-form is not setting the values to the Input fields in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to provide default values in the input field using `react-hook-form`. First I retrieve the user data from the API endpoint and then setting the state `users` to that user data. Then I pass the state `users` to the `defaultValues` of `useForm()`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from "axios";

function LoginFile() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/users/1")
      .then((res) => setUsers(res.data));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(users);
  }, [users]);

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    defaultValues: users,
  });
 return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        Email <input type="email" name="email" ref={register} /><br />
        firstname <input name="firstname" ref={register} /><br/>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
 );
}
export default LoginFile;
```

I did by the above code but didn't work as expected. All the input fields are still empty. I want to have some default values in the input field of my form.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The problem is that during the first render, `users` is the `useState` hook's initial value, which is `null`. The value only changes after the `axios.get()` request finishes, which is *after* the initial render. This means that the the default values passed to `useForm` is `null`.

The [documentation for defaultValues](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform) says the following:

> `defaultValues` are cached **on the first render** within the custom hook. If you want to reset the `defaultValues`, you should use the [`reset`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset) api.

So, you'll just need to use `reset` to reset the form manually to the values which you fetch. The documentation for `reset` says the following:

> You will need to pass `defaultValues` to `useForm` in order to `reset` the `Controller` components' value.

However, it's unclear from the documentation whether `null` is enough as the defaultValues, or if you need to pass it a proper object with fields for each input. To play it safe, let's assume it's the latter.

The code for doing this would look something like this:

```
function LoginFile() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({ email: "", firstname: "" });

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: users,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users/1").then((res) => {
      setUsers(res.data);
      reset(res.data);
    });
  }, [reset]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(users);
  }, [users]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        Email <input type="email" name="email" ref={register} />
        <br />
        firstname <input name="firstname" ref={register} />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Additionally, if the only reason for the useState hook is to store the value for `defaultValues`, you don't need it at all and can clean up the code to be:

```
function LoginFile() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { email: "", firstname: "" },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users/1").then((res) => {
      reset(res.data);
    });
  }, [reset]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        Email <input type="email" name="email" ref={register} />
        <br />
        firstname <input name="firstname" ref={register} />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Will `reset(res.data)` resets the defaultValue to the API users data like `{email: "subro@gg.com", firstname: "subrato"}`? I am asking this bcz my mindset is that reset means empty the input field.

Comment: The documentation for [reset](https://react-hook-form.com/api#reset) says: _"You can pass values as an optional argument to reset your form into the assigned default values."_.

Comment: I have `id` key in my user's data. What will be the defaultValue of id when we defining them in useForm? Is it okay with `{id: 0, email; "", firstname:""}`? I am using your first approach.

Comment: Yeah, this work. I have noticed one thing that I like to share when I set the state as `null` It is showing me an error like `cannot read property of "email" which is null'` but when I set the state as `[]` then it shows empty values to the input fields

Comment: @cbr Thank you, you are a saviour

Comment: You are a hero!

Answer (score 14):

That definitely Worked. Using the reset API and the UseEffect.

Starting with empty stings as default values and the updating them as effects with the reset. Here is my code. Was using TypeScript with Ionic here as well...

```js
const { control: editControl, handleSubmit: editSubmit, reset } = useForm<EditFormType>({
      defaultValues: {
         question: "",
         optionA: "",
         optionB: "",
         optionC: "",
         optionD: "",
      }
   });

   useEffect(() => {
      let defaults ={
         question: editQuestion?.body,
         optionA: editQuestion?.options[0].body,
         optionB: editQuestion?.options[1].body,
         optionC: editQuestion?.options[2].body,
         optionD: editQuestion?.options[3].body,
      }
      reset(defaults)
   }, [editQuestion, reset])
```

Comment: This answer was easier to follow for my problem because it didn't have all the extra noise of the other answer.

Comment: Specifying `defaultValues` for useForm may not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I will just explain my findings here, we must set defaultValue in order for reset to work, and also to get get correct isdirty value or to reset isDirty value when value reset to default. To set defaultValue, we have options to set defaultValue with useForm or use reset or resetField inside useEffect hook. Note- setValue will not set default value.