# Fetch data and then set state for editing data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to figure out (learning react currently) how to manage my react hooks. I would like as part of a CRUD operation to update a `transaction`. When the edit "url" loads the data isn't present yet. I want to fetch it and then set the state of `transactionUpdate` which is used to not alter the original transaction update before the user submits the form. Before the `transactionUpdate` data is set the rendering shouldn't happen as the fields use the `transactionUpdate` object

```
const EditTransaction = (props) => {

    const transactionID = props.match.params.id

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const getFxs = () => dispatch(fetchFxs())

    const singleTransaction = id => dispatch(fetchTransaction(transactionID))

    const currentState = useSelector(state => state)

    const transaction = currentState.TransactionsState.transaction

    const [transactionUpdate, setTransactionUpdate] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        getFxs()
        singleTransaction()
        setTransactionUpdate(transaction)
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

..... code stripped
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: For initial render you have to add initial state values otherwise it will throw error. pls find the answer in the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306943/defaultvalues-of-react-hook-form-is-not-setting-the-values-to-the-input-fields-i)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Keerthi Vijay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349155/keerthi-vijay) I found the following solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
        getFxs()
        singleTransaction()
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
        setTransactionUpdate(transaction)
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [transaction])
```