# React Hook Form - Default Value Not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a form and I have provided the default value but its not populating in the field.

```
<View style={styles.twoColumnColumn}>
  <Controller
    control={control}
    render={({ onChange, value }) => (
      <Picker
        required
        label={LocalizationService.BETA_AGONIST}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        options={betaAgonists}
        // error={errors?.[NEW_INTERACTIVE_FORM.BETA_AGONIST]}
      />
    )}
    name={'BETA_AGONIST'}
    rules={{ required: true }}
  />
</View>
```

Default value is provided like this:

```
const {
    control,
    watch,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    setError,
    errors,
    clearErrors,
    reset,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      BETA_AGONIST: someArray[0],
    },
  });
```

But the values are not being populated into the picker and I get warning BETA_AGONIST is missing in the defaultValues...

Version:     "react-hook-form": "^6.15.4",

EDIT:
I have event tried the defaultValues prop on Controller but it still doesnt work. The weird thing is that I have other pickers who have values passed same like this and they are working fine. Only this one has issue.

Comment: I have something for [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306943/defaultvalues-of-react-hook-form-is-not-setting-the-values-to-the-input-fields-i). Does that solve your concern?

Comment: You need to reset the hook form with default values.

Comment: @SubratoPattanaik man you shouldnt be hiding next time I get these errors. It worked. I moved my API call to a previous screen to load values earlier. Marked duplicate of your question

Answer (score 2):

You can directly set default values in useForm.
like this

```
 useForm({ BETA_AGONIST: someArray[0]})
```