# React useState set Value based on provided Key dynamically

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently trying to create a simple useForm Hook in React and am currently working on setting the Data dynamically for a State which is stored inside a useState Hook.

Setting the Data is working fine now but I also want to be able to save it as an Object based on the provided Key.

These two Options should work but as of now, only the First one is working.
| Key | Value | Expected Result |
| -------- | -------------- | ----- |
| userName | Simagdo| {"userName": "Simagdo"} |
| address.Street | Test | {"userName": "Simagdo", "address": {"street: "Test"} |

Until now I have the following Code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<T>({}) as T);
const handleChange = <S extends unknown>(key: keyof T, sanitizeFn?: (value: string) => S, type?: string) => (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement & HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    //let value = sanitizeFn ? sanitizeFn(e.target.value) : e.target.value;
    let value: string | number = e.target.value;

    setData({
        ...data,
        [key]: value
    });
};
```

And to set the Value I am using the following Code:

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="Username"
    value={user.userName || ''}
    placeholder={t('texts.user-name')}
    onChange={handleChange('userName')}
    required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that value should be `data.userName`. Until then your value will be always `user.userName` or ''.

On the other hand. If you're not developing new form framework I really advise you to use [react-final-form](https://final-form.org/react).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my understanding, React-Form-Hooks doesn't allow the internal custom onChange method. But you can achieve that using inline onChange

this is a new way to do it: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v7.16.0

```
const [data, setData] = useState({name ="", age=0})
<input
    type="text"
    name="Username"
    defaultValue={data?.name}
    placeholder={data?.name}
    {...register("name", { require: true, 
      onChange: (e) => { 
         // your code
         setData = ({..data,  name: e.target.value }), })}
/>
```

**I would recommend you use the Reset property of react-form-hooks to set up the initial value of form fields.**

[Set default values in React Hook Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70663158/set-default-values-in-react-hook-form)

[DefaultValues of react-hook-form is not setting the values to the Input fields in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306943/defaultvalues-of-react-hook-form-is-not-setting-the-values-to-the-input-fields-i)

Answer (score 0):

oh man, you are doing wrong change your Input component like following
name of input and state of input should be same "userName"

```
<input
type="text"
name="userName"
value={data.userName || ''}
placeholder={t('texts.user-name')}
onChange={handleChange} // or onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}
required/>
```

then change the `handleChange` function

```
const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement & HTMLSelectElement>) => {
let value: string | number = e.target.value;
let name: string = e.target.name;

setData({
    ...data,
    [name]: value
});
};
```